# changing the title of the accordion menu dynamically in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, accordion

i have created the accordion menu in angularjs using the example in
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion 
but i want the title of the accordion to be changed dynamically .I have tried doing it by jquery but it does not work in this . anyone has any idea how to do this with the above bootstrap example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All angular expressions enclosed in {{}} in html are updated dynamically, like group.title here will be updated if `$scope.group.title` changes:

`<accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">`